# Beef on Multiple Campaigns

Tags: beef

I use the Autorun Rule Engine (ARE) in BEEF to run some some targeted modules upon being hooked and this works great, but how about if I want to run two separate campaigns?  Those sent to webpage A get one set of Autorun Rules and those sent to webpage B get another set of Autorun rules.  Can you set up flags some how in the page JS configuration that could be leveraged in the ARErules .JSON file logic?

Comment: I don't think so. I guess you must start 2 different beefs to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I left time to see if any other answer to this. Finally, it seems I'm not wrong on my comment. I found on BeEF docs this: https://github.com/beefproject/beef/wiki/Autorun-Rule-Engine#matching

So you can set rules for browser A or operating system B, but not possible to set rules for surfing on website A and others for website B. So the answer is no, you can't as I said time ago in the comments. You need two BeEF to do that.

Comment: So here is what you can do....Host servers on a VPS, which gives you the ability to snapshot you main image and then create an exact copy.  Thus now you have server A and B.  To save money when not in use, simply take down server B and save its image, which costs very little.